# Unable to set the date in calendar control in Asp.Net with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to change the year and month using jquery with asp.net calender control but i am not able to change the year. May be there is a problem with calender contorol property.

Following is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var cyear = $('#<%=Ddyear.ClientID %>');
    var cmonth = $('#<%=Ddmonth.ClientID %>');

    var cal = $('#<%=Calendar1.ClientID %>');
    cyear.change(function () {
        var item = cyear.val();
        var item2 = cmonth.val();

        item = item + ',' + item2;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dashboardQuery.aspx/calanderdates",
            data: '{item:"' + item + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var sdate = Date.parse(response.d, "MM/dd/yyyy");
                dates = sdate;
                $('#<%=Calendar1.ClientID %>').attr('VisibleDate', sDate);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert(msg.status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the `VisibleDate` property on an ASP.Net calendar through jQuery, it's a server-side property, as such there is no `VisibleDate` property in the generated HTML.

You could change your code to change the date on the server-side instead, something like this would work:

```
<asp:DropDown runat="server" ID="Ddmonth" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Ddmonth_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected sub Ddmonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // depending on what is in your drop down list will affect this code
    // this code assumes that you are listing the months by number, e.g. 1 for January, 2 for February, etc.
    int selectedMonth = int.Parse(DdMonth.SelectedValue);
    int monthsToAdd = selectedMonth - Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month;
    Calendar1.VisibleDate = Calendar1.VisibleDate.AddMonths(monthsToAdd);
}
```

Comment: Hi sean, thanks for replay. I had also fine the client control using   $('#<%=Calendar1.ClientID %>').attr('VisibleDate', sDate); but it is still not working

Comment: VisibleDate is never going to work. It is not a client-side property, it exists exclusively within the server-side code. Can you post the markup for your `<asp:Calendar>` control please?

Comment: Ok I've had a look at the rendered markup for the calendar control and remembered why I stopped using them, they suck. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you can use something more flexible than the calendar control. If you're just using it to select dates, you might want to look at something like: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: i am working on event calendar. that's why i need calender control

Comment: Can't you use the built-in navigation controls to move the months?

Comment: i know that but my requirement is with dropdown control

Comment: Perhaps you can refactor then? If you were to change your drop downs to make them post back automatically (`AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Ddyear_SelectedIndexChanged"`) and then change the month on the server-side: `Calendar1.VisibleDate = dateFromDropDown;`

Comment: Edited answer to reflect my suggestion